# SQL / ActiveRecord: Limit records on a condition-basis

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, limit

The database consists of 3 models: Level, World, and Score.

```
class World < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels
  has_many :scores, through: :levels
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :world
  has_many :scores
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :level
  has_one :world, through: :level

  scope :top, -> n { limit(n).order(points: :desc) }
end
```

It is possible to get the top 5 scores of a level: `level.scores.top(5)`. Now, the client wants to see the top 5 scores for each level of one specific world. Obviously, `world.scores.top(5)` won't work. Is there a clean solution on how to getting the top 5 scores of each level in a world?

The resulting object should preferably be of ActiveRecord::Collection! What won't be sufficient for example is the following: `world.levels.map { |l| l.scores.top(5) }.flatten`. It would also be beneficial to have `Score.includes(:level).where(levels: { world_id: x })` as outset and not the other way around unless that's not possible.

While I would prefer a global solution, I can also accept a MySQL-only solution.

Thanks in advance,
Danyel.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Obviously I prefer a global solution, but I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on various sites and with a lot of help from a teammate, we eventually did find a solution that was easily includable into rails. The following query will get the top `n` scores of a level_group per level.

```
sub_query = Highscore.from("highscores s2").where("s2.level_id = levels.id").where(
  "s2.points > highscores.points"
).select("COUNT(*)").to_sql
Highscore.include(:level).where(levels: { level_group_id: id }).where("( #{sub_query} ) < ?", n)
```